# Location indicator always visible

Tags: gps, notification-bar, notification-icons, motorola

After a year or two of nothing, my Motorola Moto One (XT1941) with Android 10 again started to show location indicator 24 hours a day, 7 days a week:

[image]

Nothing, that I tried so far, worked. Restarting phone brings solution only for a few minutes, killing Google Maps also. The only workaround that I found is to permanently turn of GPS location in my phone. The moment I turn it on, I see that damn indicator again.

This is very frustrating to me. Is there anything *else* I can do to permanently get rid of it?

Comment: Unclear if you checked/tried [Google Account Help-Choose which apps use your Android phone’s location](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6179507?hl=en) You may also wish to check: [Google Account Help-Manage your Android device’s location settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3467281)

Comment: On your device, have you checked under *Settings › Location* what app(s) last accessed your location? If the indicator is permanently on, maybe some app is permanently requesting the location. To find out if it is "the last one", tap on its name there, which brings you to its details screen. There, tap "force close" to kill the app. Should the indicator promptly disappear, you've found the culprit. There's also the privacy dashboard in settings telling you which app last accessed what, having a more detailed history incl. time of last access.